# ListView not showing observablecollection, when a new collection is assigned to bound property, even though RaisePropertyChanged is called

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light, observablecollection

I have a ListView that is bound to an ObservableCollection. The problem I'm facing is that the view does not update, when I assign a new collection, even though I'm calling `RaisePropertyChanged`.

```
//TrackIO.GetTracks()
public static ObservableCollection<Track> GetTracks() 
{
     return tracks;
}

    <ListView x:Name="TrackListView" 
                  SelectionMode="Single" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ObservableTracks}"
                  SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedTrackIndex, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  >
        <!-- Column Binding matches track object properties -->
             <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Title" Width="600" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Title}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Album" Width="350" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Album}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Artist" Width="250" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Artist}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Duration" Width="200" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FormattedDuration}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
     </ListView>

    private ObservableCollection<Track> _observableTracks;
    public ObservableCollection<Track> ObservableTracks
    {
        get { return _observableTracks; }
        private set
        {
            _observableTracks = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

I'm using MVVM light to notify the viewmodel, to set the property to a different collection.

As you can see I have items in the collection, so when I assign a new collection to the ObservableTracks property. `RaisePropertyChanged()` should be called, but the view is empty/shows nothing.
[image]

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code is working fine on my machine.

ViewModel:

```
public class Track
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<Track> _observableTracks;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        DoSomething = new RelayCommand(() => ObservableTracks = new ObservableCollection<Track>() { new Track { Title = "test" } });
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Track> ObservableTracks
    {
        get { return _observableTracks; }
        private set
        {
            _observableTracks = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public RelayCommand DoSomething { get; private set; }
}
```

View:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>

<StackPanel>
    <Button Command="{Binding DoSomething}" Content="Do something" />
    <ListView x:Name="TrackListView" 
              SelectionMode="Single" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ObservableTracks}"
              SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedTrackIndex, Mode=TwoWay}"
              >
        <!-- Column Binding matches track object properties -->
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Title" Width="600" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Title}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Album" Width="350" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Album}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Artist" Width="250" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Artist}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Duration" Width="200" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FormattedDuration}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```

Have you not forget to set the DataContext of your view?

If not could you share a short example that fails?

Comment: Thanks. It works. I think the datacontext was the problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

The setter needs to be called in order to invoke the `RaisePropertyChanged` method. If it is private, it cannot be called from external code. If Resharper flags it as not changing state, you should ignore it with a comment (though it should not flag it due to the method call).

```
private ObservableCollection<Track> _observableTracks;
public ObservableCollection<Track> ObservableTracks
{
    get { return _observableTracks; }
    set
    {
        _observableTracks = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Further, it is a good pattern to check the value for equality before setting:

```
...
set
{
    if (_observableTracks == value)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Finally, `RaisePropertyChanged` makes all properties refresh, where you may only want the single property changed notification:

```
RaisePropertyChanged(() => ObservableTracks);
```

Comment: I removed the "ObservableTracks" parameter, because resharper displayed this message: The parameter name has the same as default value. That's not the problem, but thanks for trying to help.

Comment: how did you impliment INotifyPropertyChanged interface?

Comment: And why did you put private set??

Comment: I didn't. I'm using the MVVM light framework. Calling RaisePropertyChanged notifies whatever is bound to the property, of the update. It works for all other properties except for this collection.

Comment: My viewmodel extends ViewModelBase, as per MVVM light.

Comment: @HaloMediaz Your property is read only. remove private from your setter

Comment: I used private set, because I don't have the mode for binding set to twoway.